# Problems with casting (or rather not-casting)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, casting

I guess this is very basic.

I get two related warnings from xCode. Both say that I'm trying to make a pointer from integer without a cast. How can I satisfy xCode?

This is my code:

```
int tempCurrentPage = currentPageCounter;
[self tabAdd:@"New tab!" inColour:@"Red" withReference:tempCurrentPage];
```

Note: currentPageCounter is an `NSUInteger currentPageCounter;`.

My method looks like this:

```
-(void)tabAdd:(NSString *)newTabTitle inColour:(NSString *)newTabColour withReference:(int *)newTabReference
{

    NSLog(@"#string about to be added:%@", newTabTitle);
    [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:currentBookNumber] tabTitles] addObject:newTabTitle];

    NSLog(@"#string about to be added:%@", newTabColour);
    [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:currentBookNumber] tabColours] addObject:newTabColour];

    NSLog(@"#string about to be added:%@", newTabReference);
    [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:currentBookNumber] tabReference] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:newTabReference]];       

}
```

How should I do a cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in a pointer to integer at:

```
-(void)tabAdd:(NSString *)newTabTitle inColour:(NSString *)newTabColour withReference:(int *)newTabReference
```

Change this for:

```
-(void)tabAdd:(NSString *)newTabTitle inColour:(NSString *)newTabColour withReference:(NSUInteger)newTabReference
```

and in the selector call, pass the currentPageCounter directly:

```
[self tabAdd:@"New tab!" inColour:@"Red" withReference:currentPageCounter];
```

Answer (score 3):

`withReference` is expecting a `int *`, but you are passing an `int`. This is a potential bug and may crash your program. It seems that you don't need a pointer to integer in the method, just passing a integer is fine.

```
// remove the pointer for newTabRefenerce
-(void)tabAdd:(NSString *)newTabTitle inColour:(NSString *)newTabColour withReference:(int)newTabReference

// newTabReference is integer, do use %d. %@ is for NSString
NSLog(@"#string about to be added:%d", newTabReference);
```

Answer (score 1):

The incoming cast should be `(int)` and not `(int*)`. And when you log `newTabReference` log it using `%d` and not `%@`.